# issues with retrieving repositories from pypi?

Tags: python-2.7, docker, amazon-ec2

it seems like my application is failing to download the file from pypi. i'm not sure if this is a docker issue or a python issue can anyone provide some insights? thanks! I have a container running on an aws ec2 machine inside a docker-compose.

```
ez_setup.py is deprecated and when using it setuptools will be pinned to 33.1.1 since it's the last version that supports setuptools self upgrade/installation, check https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581 for more info; use pip to install setuptools
Downloading https://pypi.io/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-33.1.1.zip
Extracting in /tmp/tmp2UWvyq
Now working in /tmp/tmp2UWvyq/setuptools-33.1.1
Building a Setuptools egg in /tmp/bootstrap-xSf6w8
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'setuptools/_vendor'
/tmp/bootstrap-xSf6w8/setuptools-33.1.1-py2.7.egg
error: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/69/3584b5d1f197460194647aa12c627cb4b0b822ee1782fd6c867280f2e6d7/zc.buildout-2.13.4.tar.gz#sha256=b978b2f9317b317ee4191f78fcc4f05b1ac41bdaaae47f0956f14c8285feef63 hostname 'files.pythonhosted.org' doesn't match either of 'r.ssl.fastly.net', '*.catchpoint.com', '*.cnn.io', '*.dollarshaveclub.com', '*.eater.com', '*.fastly.picmonkey.com', '*.files.saymedia-content.com', '*.ft.com', '*.meetupstatic.com', '*.nfl.com', '*.pagar.me', '*.picmonkey.com', '*.realself.com', '*.sbnation.com', '*.shakr.com', '*.streamable.com', '*.surfly.com', '*.theverge.com', '*.thrillist.com', '*.vox-cdn.com', '*.vox.com', '*.voxmedia.com', 'eater.com', 'ft.com', 'i.gse.io', 'picmonkey.com', 'realself.com', 'static.wixstatic.com', 'streamable.com', 'surfly.com', 'theverge.com', 'vox-cdn.com', 'vox.com', 'www.joyent.com'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 193, in <module>
    "Failed to execute command:\n%s" % repr(cmd)[1:-1])
Exception: Failed to execute command:
'/usr/local/bin/python', '-c', "import sys; sys.path[0:0] = ['/tmp/bootstrap-xSf6w8/setuptools-33.1.1-py2.7.egg']; from setuptools.command.easy_install import main; main()", '-mZqNxd', '/tmp/bootstrap-xSf6w8', 'zc.buildout==2.13.4'
The command '/bin/sh -c python bootstrap.py     && bin/buildout     && ln -s $SENAITE_FILESTORAGE/ var/filestorage     && ln -s $SENAITE_BLOBSTORAGE/ var/blobstorage     && chown -R senaite:senaite $SENAITE_HOME $SENAITE_DATA     && rm -rf $SENAITE_HOME/buildout-cache/downloads/dist' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'zeoserver' failed to build
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles across this and is unaware of the source of these failures, here's the [github ticket](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978).

> Our CDN provider is deprecating non-SNI support for access to pypi.org and files.pythonhosted.org. It appears that this rollout has begun and users without SNI support can expect disruptions.